# scattering by weak potential and the adiabatic hypothesis

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory, adiabatic

In Ryder QFT, regarding the calculation of the scattering amplitude by a weak potential $V$, the potential is assumed to be switched on and off slowly using the adiabatic hypothesis. But there is a statement:"$V$ must not be switched on and off too quickly; this would imply, through Fourier transformation, that the time dependence of $V$ results in the scattering center emitting or absorbing energy." My question is what exactly this statement means, I don't really see it very clearly.

Comment: I have thought about this for a while and an intuitive explanation I came up with so far is from a semiclassical point of view. suppose at time $t_1$ the scattering potential is 0, and the wavepacket is located at $\vec{x}_1$. After some short time at $t_2$ the potential is switched on to be $V$ and the wavepacket is located at $\vec{x}_2$. Then for the wavepacket, the potential changes by $V$ for a position change of $|\Delta \vec{x}|\propto \Delta t$, therefore, the wavepacket will experience a kick proportional to $\frac{V}{\Delta t}$, which will be large if $\Delta t$ is small

Answer (score 1):

Actually the adiabatic hypothesis is usually not required in potential scattering. In case the potential has sufficient decay in coordinate space one can show the existence of the Moller wave operators from which the scattering operator is then obtained. With some modifications this even works for the slowly decaying Coulomb potential. Thus no switching on and off of the potential is required. 
About V not being switched too rapidly, think of a ground state atom with an incident electromagnetic field wavepacket. If the field amplitude changes slowly the atom returns to its original state after the field has gone. But if the field amplitude changes rapidly, say with an atomic excitation frequency, then there is a finite probability that the atom is left in an excited state.

Comment: I see, so that's why Ryder mentioned Fourier transform. A sharp peak in time domain ended up with a broad spectrum in frequency domain, which very likely contains some large frequencies to stimulate the level transition. thanks.